# AR Mailer with changing settings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, mailer, ar-mailer

we're running ARMailer in one of our projects right now.
It's working fine but as different customers are allowed to send confirmation emails via this service we want to offer them the possibility to use their own SMTP settings for that.

Is there a way to change ARMailer settings on the fly?

Or is there an ARMailer alternative maybe which abstracts this better?

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end was:
I took the ARMailer gem and took a copy of it.
After that, modified the email delivery action and started the daemon from my new custom folder. Works fine. Will create a custom some day...

Comment: I'd love to see your solution. This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

this: [Using multiple SMTP accounts with Rails & ActionMailer](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/03/using-multiple-smtp-accounts-w.html)
 has a nice example using yaml for storing the multiple configurations, but can easily be adapted to use the db